# Postgrex migration fail, undefined object jsonb

Tags: postgresql, phoenix-framework, ecto

I am trying to use `guardian_db` for managing jwts.

However, when I try to migrate `guardian_db` schema, it triggers an error, `(undefined_object) type "jsonb" does not exist`.

I found a similar issue on github ecto repository, https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/issues/1078. It says jsonb is supported from Postgres 9.4.

I am using Postgres 9.6.1 but still experiencing this issue.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What does `select version()` show you?

Comment: It shows `psql (9.6.1, server 9.3.13)`.

Comment: That's not the output of `select version();` - but anyway it does show that your server is running Postgres 9.3 (which is no longer supported), not 9.6